# php json_decode not working, json_last_error() thows 4

Tags: php, json

My English is poor. I'm sorry if there is anything rude.
Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

When I use PHP function json_decode(), i get null and json_last_error() throws 4.
Thanks for helping!

my PHP code is

```
$str = file_get_contents("cache.txt");
$str = htmlspecialchars_decode($str);
$arr = json_decode($str, true);
print_r($arr);
echo $errorinfo = json_last_error();
```

the content of File named cache.txt is:

```
[[1,[0,"wWfxgeyEgrRf1M",["https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q\u003dtbn%3AANd9GcTFekou1VcAkVW23s69_Q53CsUJD0syjACwY0jHbRYcRIcr5cyp",225,225],["https://www.hijordan.com/image/cache/catalog/Jordan-Retro-1/Jordan-Retro-1-16-1080x1080.jpg",1080,1080],null,2,"rgb(160,42,51)",null,false,{"2001":[null,null,null,21,18,3,3,null,null,null,[]],"2003":[null,"M3A7LEiRdcA0DM","https://www.aljadid.com/efabshop/air-jordan-retro-1-red-black-white-p-16.html","Nike Air Jordan Retro 1 Red Black White - Buy Air Jordan 1 Retro ...",null,false,null,null,null,false,null,null,"Al Jadid",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,false,false,false,{"26":[null,2]}],"2006":[null,[4.0,null,"Air Jordan Retro 1 red black white",null,"A stepping stone to the world of Air Jordan is the Original air jordan 1  (I) White Black Red, which was worn by Michael Jordan the majority of the  ...",null,true,5,60.85,"USD"]],"2008":[null,"Nike Air Jordan Retro 1 Red Black White ..."],"183836587":["aljadid.com"]}],null,[177,158,null,null,null,177,177,null,null,-10,null,null,false,true,null,null,[]],0,null,null,"wWfxgeyEgrRf1M",1,null,null,null,null,[[1580879352798185,178652430,3708684377],null,2]],[1,[0,"sFUMQKdZQFRaGM",["https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q\u003dtbn%3AANd9GcSV5L3VvYWthX-IG9QO5QfLN_6eLvA687_og435LmF6_5NmGSI4",225,225],["https://www.hijordan.com/image/cache/catalog/air-jordan-12/air-jordan-12-49-1080x1080.jpg",1080,1080],null,2,"rgb(160,58,51)",null,false,{"2001":[null,null,null,21,18,3,6,null,null,null,[]],"2003":[null,"pTPqQEjGfZF7JM","https://togaf9-cert.opengroup.org/bcabshop/air-jordan-12-retro-black-varsity-red-p-1138.html","Air Jordan 12 Retro Black Varsity Red , Price: $89.90 - Air Jordan ...",null,false,null,null,null,false,null,null,"TOGAF? 9 Certification",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,false,false,false,{"26":[null,2]}],"2006":[null,[4.0,null,"Air Jordan 12 Retro Black Varsity Red","Nike","You should not miss the chance if you have not got one like the Air Jordan  12 Retro Black Varsity Red. Fine craftsmanship with premium materials like  ...",null,true,5,89.9,"USD"]],"2008":[null,"Air Jordan 12 Retro Black Varsity Red ..."],"183836587":["togaf9-cert.opengroup.org"]}],],]
```

Comment: That means your JSON has a syntax error, run the JSOn through a validator and you'll see where it fails.

Comment: Actually, looks like your trailing commas at the end has to be removed, and then it'll work. At the end, replace `]}],],]` with `]}]]]`

Comment: trailing commas creating issue. remove them and it will work. what @Qirel  suggested.